# How do I implement action={% url '......' %} in django-form

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to know the equivalent using `<form action={% url '......' %}>` in django-form(i.e. using `forms.ModelForm` class).

How do I define the action url of my form in djano-form? it can be easily done in HTML using action attribute of form as `action={% url....`

Comment: could you elaborate more on your question? What do you need to do?

Comment: I need to define the action url of a form in django-form. In HTML form it can be done using: action={% url '......' %}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form action in views.py will run when you click `<button type='submit'> Submit </button>`  in your `<form>`. If it's not what you want:

That is how you can trigger a view function from html :

views.py

```
def YourAction(request, arg):
    # do something
    return redirect('/anywhere') # you need to return something
```

urls.py

```
from .views import YourAction
urlpatterns = [
   path('dosomething/<arg>', YourAction, name='action_name'),
]
```

your html

```
<form action='{% url 'action_name' arg %}'>
   <button type='submit'> Submit! </button>
</form>
```

You don't have to use form. You can just use `<a href='{% url 'action_name' arg %}'> Do Something! </a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can change it, also,  in View (views.py):

```
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import YOUR_FORM_MODEL

def myView(request):
  if request. Method == 'GET':
        form = YOUR_FORM_MODEL()
        form.helper.form_action = reverse('appname:testme')
        mydata = {'form': form}
        return HttpResponse(render(request, 'appname/custom_page.html', context=mydata))
```

and add in Your urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'appname'
urlpatterns = [
    path('test-my-custom-form-send-path', views.myView, name='testme'),
]
```

in your template (custom_page.html):

```
{% extends 'appname/base_html_file.html' %}{% load crispy_forms_tags %}{% load static %}
{% crispy form %}
```